# How to convert a .py file to an executable in Linux/Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I have a **Python .py Program** that I want to execute/**run** by directly **double-clicking** on the **file**....
or alternatively Terminal commands for it if possible....

I used **chmod +x myfile.py** but it shows
"bash: ./myfile.py: no such file or directory"

Answer (score 3):

On unix systems, Python scripts can be made executable using the following process:

**Add this line as the first line in the script:**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

At the unix command prompt, type the following to make myexe.py executable:

```sh
$ chmod +x myexe.py
```

Move **myexe.py** into your `bin` directory, and it will be runnable from anywhere.

```sh
$ cp myexe.py /usr/bin
```

OR

```sh
$ cp myexe.py /usr/local/bin
```

**So myexe.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("Hello This is executable python script")
```

Now Go to terminal and type myexe.py

```sh
$ myexe.py
Hello This is excutable python script
```

If you want to **run by double-clicking** remove .py extention

[source link](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/app_c.html)